# How to split 422 error into field/error with axios request?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

In my vuejs3 app saving data with axios, when I got 422 validation error
I try to catch it and show message which fields were invalid. I try to read error responce onject,
but failed. I do like :

```
axios.put(requestUrl, currencyData, credentials).then(({data}) => {
    isPageUpdating.value = false
    showPopupMessage('Currency Editor', 'Currency updated successfully !', 'success')
    router.push({path: '/admin/currencies'})
}).catch((error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 422 ) {
        console.log('error.response.data:::')
        console.log(error.response.data)
        console.log('error.response.data.errors:::')
        console.log(error.response.data.errors)
        console.log(typeof error.response.data.errors)
        if (typeof error.response.data.errors === 'object') {
            let errorsArray = Object.values(error.response.data.errors)
            let errStr = ''
            errorsArray.map((errorField, errorKey) => {
                console.log('errorField::')
                console.log(errorField)
                console.log(typeof errorField)
                console.log('errorKey::')
                console.log(errorKey)
                console.log('errorsArray[errorKey]::')
                console.log(errorsArray['errorKey'])
                
            })

            showPopupMessage('Currency Editor', errStr, 'warn')
        }
        return
    }
})
```

I tried to get errors text in errStr above and failed
I see in the browser's console : https://prnt.sc/xyy7ql

```
"axios": "^0.20.0-0",
"vue": "^3.0.0",
"yup": "^0.29.3"
```

How can I get invalid fields/errors list as text ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to get an array of values from the `data.errors` object

```js
let errorsArray = Object.values(error.response.data.errors)
```

and data.errors looks like:

```js
{
  "name": ["error 1", "error 2"]
}
```

if you are then trying to loop over the keys of `data.errors` it's not going to work with

```js
errorsArray.map((errorField, errorKey) => {}
```

because `Object.values` returns an array, where the key/index is a number `[0..]`

So that's why your `errorKey` is 0;

If you want the errors from the `name` field, you could do

```js
let errorsArray = Object.values(error.response.data.errors.name)
```

but if the keys are names of fields...

```js
let errorsKeysArr = Object.keys(error.response.data.errors)
errorsKeysArr.map((key) => {
  const errorField = error.response.data.errors[key]
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks!
It was usefull to get string error text splitted  and to show it in a 
message function.
Also if there is a way to show this error in field definition ?
   <ErrorMessage name="name" as="p" class="validation_error"/>
or in other words to put this errors in stack of validation errors ?